# What is the preferred way to write "with a capital [letter]" kind of phrases?

Tags: capitalization, phrase-usage

In written text, which of these is correct:

1. That boy is crazy with a capital C!
2. That boy is crazy with a capital 'C'!
3. That boy is crazy with a capital c!
4. That boy is crazy with a capital 'c'!
5. That boy is Crazy!

Comment: I do not understand. Number 1, obviously. 2-4 are not even an option, and 5 is from a different question entirely.

Comment: This is largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, to the [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) of your preference.

Comment: If you are representing dialog, your first option is probably the best.  And some would insert a comma after "crazy".  If you're going with #5 (which is a better choice when not representing dialog), then it would be best to italicize *crazy* rather than mess with case at all.

Comment: [Trouble in River City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI_Oe-jtgdI)

Answer (score 2):

Two dictionaries I checked show usage of the type 1: *That boy is crazy with a capital C!*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with-a-capital-a-b-etc)

> said after the name of a particular quality to say that it is very strong, using its first letter
>
> *He's trouble with a capital T!*

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+a+capital)

> 1. In the most extreme form or degree.
>      *I am hungry with a capital H! Let's eat!
>
>      No, it's not an emergency with a capital E. I can wait until the end of the day.*
> 2. In the most typical, formal, or traditional form.
>      *Well, it's not literature with a capital L, but it's still a good story.*

Answer (score 1):

"That boy is crazy" is different to "That boy is Crazy". The capitalisation is used for emphasis.

This use of capitalisation has resulted in the phrase "with a capital [letter]" as a way of indicating when speaking that *if it were written* it would have the capitalisation.

When writing, you would therefore most likely only write "with a capital [letter]" if you were writing / quoting someone's speech, or if you wanted to use the idiomatic phrase.

As far as punctuation around the letter, any of your options are fine and would be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The online [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=with+a+capital) uses 1.

> Man, I am Hungry with a capital H!

Comment: Urban Dictionary dictates punctuation style for written English?

Comment: @choster no but the phrase as used is slang and the Urban Dictionary is a good source for slang. At a minimum, following the Urban Dictionary ensures that you are at least [cool](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cool). :-)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56: Actually, I would rather not have the same body temperature as the cucumber in my fridge.

Comment: Each to his own.